# PHP: Slim Framework Exception Handling

Tags: php, error-handling, slim

I just finished creating an API application with slim framework, initially, in my code I use a dependency container to handle all exceptions thrown, the code is below.

```
//Add container to handle all exceptions/errors, fail safe and return json
$container['errorHandler'] = function ($container) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($container) {
        //Format of exception to return
        $data = [
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
        return $container->get('response')->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->write(json_encode($data));
    };
};
```

But instead of throwing a 500 `Server Error` all the time I would like to add other HTTPS reponse code. I wonder if I could get help on how to go about that.

```
public static function decodeToken($token)
{
    $token = trim($token);
    //Check to ensure token is not empty or invalid
    if ($token === '' || $token === null || empty($token)) {
        throw new JWTException('Invalid Token');
    }
    //Remove Bearer if present
    $token = trim(str_replace('Bearer ', '', $token));

    //Decode token
    $token = JWT::decode($token, getenv('SECRET_KEY'), array('HS256'));

    //Ensure JIT is present
    if ($token->jit == null || $token->jit == "") {
        throw new JWTException('Invalid Token');
    }

    //Ensure User Id is present
    if ($token->data->uid == null || $token->data->uid == "") {
        throw new JWTException("Invalid Token");
    }
    return $token;
}
```

The problem is even more from functions like the above one, since slim framework decides to handle all exceptions implicitly, I have no access to use `try catch` to catch any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that hard, it is simple. Rewrite the code:

```
container['errorHandler'] = function ($container) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($container) {
        //Format of exception to return
        $data = [
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
        return $container->get('response')->withStatus($response->getStatus())
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->write(json_encode($data));
    };
}
```

So what does this code do? You basically pass a `$response` as before, and what this code does is that it gets the status code from the `$response` object and passes it to the `withStatus()` method.

[Slim Documentation for referring to status.](http://docs.slimframework.com/response/status/)

Comment: Yeah, that works but the problem is that I use this container to capture custom thrown exceptions from different methods that do no have access to the $response object, so I cannot set the status code from those functions that throw the exceptions and slim framework does not allow me to capture this exceptions.

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge IMHO, you should be creating a new object of the `Response` class and then passing it.

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Also, for your new problem, create a new question.

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge If this works, please tick this. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `withJson()` method of `Slim\Http\Response` Object

```
class CustomExceptionHandler
{

    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, Exception $exception)
    {
        $errors['errors'] = $exception->getMessage();
        $errors['responseCode'] = 500;

        return $response
            ->withStatus(500)
            ->withJson($errors);
    }
}
```

and if you are using dependency injection you could do

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

//error handler
$container['errorHandler'] = function (Container $c) {
  return new CustomExceptionHandler();
};
```